# Typescript higher order function with property injection

Tags: typescript, typescript-generics

I'd like to know how to compose functions that take an object as the only argument, but each higher order function appends a property. For example, I have a function that accepts a context. And I want to wrap that function with a `withCookies` and then a `withToken` function, and have access to both `cookies` and `token` on the final function.

```js
withCookies(
  withToken(
    (ctx) => {
      console.log(ctx.cookies) // Record<string, string>
      console.log(ctx.token) // string
    }
  )
)
```

What would be the the typescript signature for this kind of higher order function?

Comment: What you mean by saying higher? do you mean `withCookies` function or the `(ctx) => {}` callback?

Comment: because in this case at first will be called 1. `(ctx) => {}` 2. `withToken` and then `withCookies`

Comment: @AshotAleqsanyan I mean withCookies function. So, you wrap the (ctx) => function within withToken, and withToken within withCookies.

Comment: Sounds to me like you're looking for mixins.

Answer (score 1):

You can certainly write call signatures for `withCookies()` and `withToken()`, and even write a `withProps()` function that can generate both of those.  But one issue you will encounter is with [type inference](https://www.typescriptlang.org/docs/handbook/type-inference.html): the compiler will probably not be able to [contextually type](https://www.typescriptlang.org/docs/handbook/type-inference.html#contextual-typing) the `ctx` callback parameter in your innermost function, because the functions in question need to be [generic](https://www.typescriptlang.org/docs/handbook/generics.html), and generic type parameter inference often doesn't play very nicely with contextual typing (see such issues as [microsoft/TypeScript#33042](https://github.com/microsoft/TypeScript/issues/33042) and [microsoft/TypeScript#38872](https://github.com/microsoft/TypeScript/issues/38872) for examples of this limitation).  In order to get your code to work, you will probably need to manually specify some types along the way so that the compiler understands what you are doing.

---

First let's define the `Cookies` and `Token` interfaces to have a name for the objects you're talking about:

```
interface Cookies {
  cookies: Record<string, string>
}
interface Token {
  token: string;
}
```

Then the `withCookies()` function should be generic in some object type `T`.  It *takes* a callback function of type `(ctx: T & Cookies) => void`, and returns a function of type `(ctx: T) => void`.  Like this:

```
/* 
declare const withCookies: <T extends object>(
  cb: (ctx: T & Cookies) => void
) => (ctx: T) => void 
*/
```

And `withToken()` has the analogous type where `Cookies` is replaced by `Token`:

```
/* 
declare const withToken: <T extends object>(
  cb: (ctx: T & Token) => void
) => (ctx: T) => void 
*/
```

---

That the signatures are so similar implies that you might have a `withProps()` function that can spit these out.  Here's one way to write it:

```
const withProps = <U extends object>(u: U) =>
  <T extends object>(cb: (ctx: T & U) => void) =>
    (ctx: T) => cb({ ...ctx, ...u });
```

So `withCookies` is what you get when you call `withProps()` with a parameter of type `Cookies`:

```
const withCookies = withProps<Cookies>(
  { cookies: { a: "hello", b: "goodbye" } }
);
```

and `withToken` is what you get when you call `withProps()` with a parameter of type `Token`:

```
const withToken = withProps<Token>(
  { token: "token" }
);
```

You can verify that those two functions have the call signatures declared above.

---

So now we try to call these functions and see the compiler get unhappy with contextual typing:

```
const badResult = withCookies(
  withToken(
    (ctx) => {
      console.log(ctx.cookies) // error! Property 'cookies' does not exist on type 'never'
      console.log(ctx.token) // error! Property 'token' does not exist on type 'never'
    }
  )
);
// const badResult: (ctx: never) => void
```

Oops, the compiler infers that the inner `ctx` is of type `never`, the impossible type. The `T` parameters for both `withCookies()` and `withToken()` were also inferred to be `never`.  The interaction of generic and contextual type inference has failed to be useful here, and so the body of your callback has errors.  While `badResult()` would behave properly at runtime, it would be nice to clear up the compiler errors.

---

One way to fix the errors is to explicitly annotate the type of the `ctx` callback parameter as `Cookies & Token`:

```
const result = withCookies(
  withToken(
    (ctx: Cookies & Token) => {
      console.log(ctx.cookies)
      console.log(ctx.token)
    }
  )
);
// const result: (ctx: object) => void
```

Another is to explicitly specify some generic type parameters; in this case, calling `withToken` with `T` specified to be `Cookies` works:

```
const alsoResult = withCookies(
  withToken<Cookies>(
    (ctx) => {
      console.log(ctx.cookies)
      console.log(ctx.token)
    }
  )
);
// const alsoResult: (ctx: object) => void
```

Either way produces a final function that takes any object.  When we test it, we can see the objects passed into `withProps()` have propagated into our inner callback as desired:

```
result({});
/*
[LOG]: {
  "a": "hello",
  "b": "goodbye"
} 
[LOG]: "token" 
*/
```

---

[Playground link to code](https://www.typescriptlang.org/play?jsx=0#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-OKsAiEtlivV2tjhtN5urjtdnt9+SD2DD0fjyfT9CztP3OxCB5cjd+gNBgqhqBIpwCG-1h6Pq8nqsC-CGYbCmMUYQAmgLIIaNBwdIbqZMC5Sog6NApnO9gZlmOYgHmOgFuhBTPg+JQLgRy4kauFGJjy0gUaqb6gTA4Hfr+zgWuwQESN07HJDsEAgMG35QUCQywfMcZGlMZEQFa9i2jhlG6pAi6EcRTikdJDGJhpok0URK4sgZ0hMTALGvqWfrCaJ4lhtxAi8VA-GSJxYZeBEr4vJIADaAAyADyADiAC6AiptIGzJBsmzbHsBwBPMGyMAlJxnCAFzXBskhhCSwXhVFJyrrcXrkhIQA)